# Playwright: a buffer is incorrectly serialized when passing it to page.evaluateHandle?

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, playwright

I need to emulate a file dropping from the file system to a page.
So I use this example: https://charliedigital.com/2021/12/20/simulate-drag-and-drop-of-files-with-playwright/

```
let fileBuffer = await fs.readFileSync(itemFilePath)
const dataTransfer = await buildTabPage.page.evaluateHandle((fileBuffer) => {
    const dt = new DataTransfer();

    console.log(JSON.stringify(fileBuffer))

   const file = new File([fileBuffer.toString('hex')], '140185A.zip', { type: 'application/octet-stream' });
   dt.items.add(file);
   return dt ;
}, fileBuffer);

await buildTabPage.page.dispatchEvent('.file-dropzone', 'drop', { dataTransfer });
```

It works, the drop event is triggered and I see the file coming to the backend.

The problem is that inside the function each buffer chain item looks like an object instead of a simple number.

After reading the file, the `fileBuffer` matches the buffer that comes to the backend when I drop a file manually. If I print it, it looks like a values chain:

```
 [
    80,
    75,
    3,
    4
    ...
]
```

But inside the `evaluateHandle` each buffer's item looks like an object:

```
{
    k: '0', 
    v: {
        n: 80
    }
}
```

Instead of just `80`.

As far as I see, this happens in `node_modules\playwright-core\lib\protocol\serializers.js -> function serializeValue(value, handleSerializer, visited)`

So when I  call the `fileBuffer.toString('hex')` it does not provide the file content. instead, it provides the `[object Object]` output.

And I cannot convert it to buffer again there, as the `Buffer` is undefined in that context.

How to properly pass a buffer into the page context?

Comment: Something similiar happened to me last week. This object-like behavior seems to occur when JSON data is loaded without a root element. Can you try the following workaround by changing `correctBuffer` to `correctBuffer.default` in the last line of code?

Comment: @Bouke Seems like the `default` property does not exist on the buffer object. And I'm reading the binary zip file, not json, if I got your point correctly

Comment: The JSON file being an array of objects, this worked for me, though I do not fully fathom why.
`import * as TestData from '../test-data/country-codes..json'; 
let testData = TestData.default;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to pass not the entire buffer but [the only buffer items](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/14420) chain into the `evaluateHandle` function (or to pass the hex string instead of the buffer).

```
let fileBuffer = await fs.readFileSync(itemFilePath)
const dataTransfer = await buildTabPage.page.evaluateHandle((fileBuffer) => {
        const dt = new DataTransfer();
        const file = new File([new Uint8Array(fileBuffer)], '140185A.zip', { type: 'application/octet-stream' });
        dt.items.add(file);
        return dt;
}, fileBuffer.toJSON().data); // or fileBuffer.toString('hex')
```